# PDO execute in a if statment

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm not sure if i'm doing this right.

This is the problem:

```
if ($result->execute() && $result2->execute()){}
```

Is this something that can be done or not?

My goal is to do something inside IF only if both queries works.

I couldn't find nothing online about that.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Note that a query is still considered successful even if it doesn't find any matching rows. Failure is just something like a syntax error or a problem communicating with the database server.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this. PDO's `execute()` statement returns `true` on success and `false` on failure. I would change the style somewhat so it's easier to read, but there's no reason you can't do this.

```php
$success1 = $result->execute();
$success2 = $result2->execute();

if ( $success1 and $success2 ) {
    // Do stuff here on failure
}
else {
    // Do stuff on failure here
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have a quick question about "and".
Is there any difference between "and" and &&?

Comment: @SuperRadio: `and` and `&&` are equivalent in php. I prefer to use the keyword `and` since it's slightly easier to read.

Comment: Personally I think it's better in the IF, because once one of the conditions is false, PHP stops evaluating the condition, meaning if the 1st query fails the second is not even ran, outside it would always run both queries, but that depends on what they plan to do after, Of course....  However I would use `&&` instead of `and` just looks weird `lol`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: That's a good point. I have no idea as to which is desirable here...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix do you have telegram?

Comment: Oh and the `and` and `&&` are not exactly the same, one has precedence over the other, in the order they are evaluated.  But In this example that doesn't matter.

Comment: telegram? I have a smart phone, and I know morse code a bit, like `...---...`  lol

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix .. / -- . .- -. / - .... . / - . .-.. . --. .-. .- -- / .- .--. .--. :)

Comment: No, never heard of it. https://morsecode.scphillips.com/translator.html  ha ha I cheated.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix me too lol I used the same website.
I would like to should you the code, maybe you know why it's not working.